# PHP while(): how to stop after three times?

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to make a PHP photo gallery (yes, I've tried other solutions, none work with the setup I want) and I am trying to make this `while` loop stop after three times, because I want to show three thumbnails per table row. Here's my current code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { echo "
<td><a href='URL/".$row2['file']."'><img src='URL/".$row2['file']."' width='200' height='106' /></a></td>
"; } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

I don't remember learning anything about stopping PHP loops, so please help! It'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be clear -- you want to STOP your loop, or you want to add a new row to your table? The two are very different things, and your comments seem to indicate the latter.

Comment: I want to add another row after three images, and continue until it reaches the 12th image aka the end of the 4th row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So what you actually want is 3 images per row. I think this will work:

```
<table>
  <?php 
    $i = 0;
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
      if($i%3==0)
        echo "<tr>"; 
      echo "<td><a href='URL/".$row2['file']."'><img src='URL/".$row2['file']."' width='200' height='106' /></a></td>";
      if($i%3==2)
        echo "</tr>";
      $i++;
    }
    if($i%3!=0)
      echo "</tr>";
  ?>
</table>
```

Comment: It works! :o! but how can I stop it at the 4th row/12th image? unless it does that...

Comment: if you only want 12 images then I suggest you just limit your query to 12 results. Or you can just add if($i==12) break; after $i++;

Comment: Add `LIMIT 12` to your SQL query :)

Comment: i think using limit is better though

Comment: For reference, `%` is a modulo operator -- it returns the remainder of the first number divided by the second.

Comment: Forgot to mention it works, have a small problem with displaying a third page but that's because I've changed the code, once again thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php 
$i=1;
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { echo "
<td><a href='URL/".$row2['file']."'><img src='URL/".$row2['file']."' width='200' height='106' /></a></td>
"; 
if($i>=3) break;
$i++;

} ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: BTW if you want to add new table row you don't need to stop loop with `brake`
You can check if $i%3==0 and then close and create new table row

Comment: Right now, this is the solution that's working for me, besides this confusing $i%3==0 part lol. It does show the first three images, I know there are two more which need to be in a second row.... which I am stuck on.

Comment: Why don't you just use a for loop? http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: @MikeMurko like I said, I really don't do much with loops and the manual confuses me lol

Comment: Then this solution will probably work for you, but I would suggest learning how a tool works before you use it. Pick up a PHP programming book if the manual is too confusing. It will help you!

Comment: I've been programming small projects in PHP for over two years, just never understood loops :/

Answer (score 0):

try adding an AND to the while and compare to a counter
while($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result) && $i < 3)

set $i to 0 before the loop

Comment: of course you need to increment your counter $i inside the loop

Comment: you may need to isolate the assignment statement from the &&.  Try something like:  while (($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) && ($i < 3))

Answer (score 0):

why not limit the results returned in the original MySQL query? you can add limit to your Query like this:

```
limit 3
```

that way $result will only have the three rows so no need for extra PHP and less data from the DB in memory

Comment: yes but then I need 3 more images in the second row, there is four rows total. 4*3=12 images

Comment: ah, wel then in that case you need to tweak your while loop.. set up the counter and for every 3rd loop, echo a closing </td> and opening <td>, then reset your counter to 0... or use $i%3==0 to determine if the count is divisible by 3

Answer (score -1):

you can add a counter, like:

```
$nr = 1;
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
if ($nr < 4) {
do your thing;
}
$nr++;
}
```

Comment: not so good solution as it will still get next results from db - but just not display it